# Laravel 5.2 blade route to resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

The documentation says:

> If the named route defines parameters, you may pass the parameters as
>   the second argument to the route function. The given parameters will
>   automatically be inserted into the URL in their correct positions:

```
Route::get('user/{id}/profile', ['as' => 'profile', function ($id) {
    //
}]);

$url = route('profile', ['id' => 1]);
```

If i do have a **nested** resource route by using `Route::resource(...)` twice, i will get a named route wich contains a placeholder like

```
employees.{employee}.images.index
```

How can i create a route for this nested resource using the blade templating engine?

I thought about

```
route('employees.{employee}.images.index', ['employee' => $employee->id]);
```

but that does not work. I know i can "manually" create the routes, but this will make them less maintainable.

**Update 1**
I know i can name the routes manually and then use the given name. But if there is a way without naming them i would prefer it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to add anything like `employee` into a route name. Run `php artisan route:list` command and you will see real names of all routes (look at column called `Name`), created by `resource` clause. Then just use them like usual:

```
route('employees.images.index', ['employee' => $employee->id]);
```

Also, you can [name resource routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-naming-resource-routes).

Comment: no this is not the case, these placesholders are inserted by laravel if you nest resources. `employees.{employee}.images.index` is the name from the command you mentioned

Comment: If it doesn't work for you, you can name resource controller routes: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-naming-resource-routes

Comment: yes this is true, i know about that. I just wondered if there is a way using the generated routes, i should add this to my question